# Can we use sql database on pythonista or replit on ipad9?

Tags: database, ipad, replit, pythonista

I want to make a project from scratch and need to use sql database only. Is there any way in which I can integrate sql database to my code on say, pythonista. If yes, then how can i access the sql db on my iPad?

Can i use replit.com for the same? I am considering to purchase pythonista if that isn’t possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use SQL in any version of Python, including Pythonista and most likely Replit, is to use SQLite. SQLite3 has been included with Python since version 2.5.

Here is a very simple example of a widget in Pythonista 3 that reads from a SQLite database of quotes and displays a random daily quote.

```
#!python3

'''
This widget script shows a daily quote
Jerry Stratton astoundingscripts.com
'''

import appex, ui
import random, sqlite3, time

def main():
    v = ui.View(frame=(0, 0, 320, 220))
    v.background_color = 0.16, 0.55, 0.52
    hPadding = 30
    quoteBox = ui.Label(frame=(hPadding, 0, 320 - 44 - hPadding, 220), flex='wh')
    quoteBox.font = ('Menlo', 14)
    quoteBox.text_color = 'white'
    quoteBox.number_of_lines = 0
    v.add_subview(quoteBox)
    appex.set_widget_view(v)
    quoteBox.text = dailyFortune

def getDailyFortune():
    quote = "Exercise builds strong code."
    quote += "\n—John M. Nevison"

    connection = sqlite3.connect('../data/quotes.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    quotes = list(cursor.execute('SELECT quote, speaker FROM quotes WHERE LENGTH(quote) < 220 ORDER BY added DESC'))
    connection.close()
    if quotes:
        # seed that switches at midnight local time
        dailySeed = time.time() - time.timezone
        # make it switch at 4am
        dailySeed -= 4*60*60
        dailySeed //= (24 * 60 * 60)
        random.seed(dailySeed)
        quote = random.choice(quotes)
        quote, speaker = quote
        if speaker:
            quote += '—' + speaker

    return quote
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dailyFortune = getDailyFortune()
    main()
```

The important lines are:

```
import sqlite3

…

connection = sqlite3.connect(FILEPATH)
cursor = connection.cursor()
quotes = list(cursor.execute(SQLSTATEMENT))
connection.close()
```

Which makes a standard Python SQL connection to an existing database and reads all matching rows as a list. You can read more about [SQLite and Python in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Oh, ohk.. I clearly wasn’t aware of it. Thank You :)